# CodeIgniter\Session\Exceptions\SessionException. Session: Configured save path "{0}" is not writable by the PHP process

Tags: codeigniter

```
SYSTEMPATH/Session/Handlers/FileHandler.php at line 123
SYSTEMPATH/Session/Handlers/FileHandler.php : 123   —  CodeIgniter\Session\Exceptions\SessionException::forWriteProtectedSavePath ( arguments )

{PHP internal code}   —  CodeIgniter\Session\Handlers\FileHandler->open ( arguments )
SYSTEMPATH/Session/Session.php : 1027   —   session_start()
SYSTEMPATH/Session/Session.php : 226   —  CodeIgniter\Session\Session->startSession ()
SYSTEMPATH/Config/Services.php : 714   —  CodeIgniter\Session\Session->start ()
```

I am using ci4 and I have created a login page. When I am going to load the login page it shows some exception error.

What is the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: check your access rights to the writable folder in project root folder. Give +w to it

Comment: i am a beginner could you please elaborate what actually have to do?

Comment: depending on the OS you are working on, check if the writable folder which is found at the root of you application if you have the read-write-execute rights. if the write is not assigned, then do it

Comment: write is assigned but still same error

Comment: finally i have done